# How to figure out which substance has the highest osmotic pressure?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, pressure, osmosis

In preparing for an exam and I'm trying to solve the following question. I'm clueless. What should I do?

> Which of the following water solutions has the highest osmotic pressure?
>
> \begin{align}
> \tag1 \pu{0.1 mol/kg} &~ \ce{NaCl}\\
> \tag2 \pu{0.1 mol/kg} &~ \ce{KF}\\
> \tag3 \pu{0.1 mol/kg} &~ \text{sucrose}\\
> \tag4 \pu{0.1 mol/kg} &~ \ce{MgCl2}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ce{MgCl2}$ has the highest osmotic pressure because it breaks up into three ions in water, as opposed to all the others, which only break up into two.